# Cakephp: afterSave() on insert only?

Tags: cakephp

I want to detect if a new record was inserted or an old record was updated in afterSave(), but I have no idea how.

I thought about writing a config variable in the beforeSave() (where I can detect an insert, if the id isn't set) but maybe that's not a safe way of doing it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it using ***[afterSave( $model, $created )](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model-behavior#method-ModelBehaviorafterSave)*** function.

Because, the ***second argument*** of the `afterSave()` function is `Boolean` and will `true` if a ***new row is created*** else it will gives you `false`.

Comment: You are correct. Though, technically, he is using the afterSave( $model, $created ), just not implementing it properly if leaving the parameters out in his model. PHP 5.4 will throw a warning if it has been implemented as afterSave().

Comment: The link is dead now and the `afterSave` API is also different: `afterSave(boolean $created, array $options = array())`; [more info](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#aftersave)

Answer (score 2):

You can check this by writing the following lines of code here:

```
public function afterSave(Event $event, Entity $entity, array $options) {
    if ($entity->isNew()) {
        // do whatever you need to do here.
    }
}
```

Comment: It's important to understand that this answer works for CakePHP 3+, but the original question was referencing version 1.X or 2.X, based on the date that it was asked.

Answer (score 0):

passing the id (when record updated) and saving it right after saveall or save
can help too. 
for example;
$this->set('id', $this->MyModule->id);